# Getting the headlines and headline links from NPR.org with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble doing this and can't find a good way to select them all. I need to get the live updates as well as the normal headlines. Basically every bolded headline on the site. Also, I need to get the embedded link that activates when these are clicked. I have some basic knowledge of HTML and have webscraped a few things before, but am struggling with this for some reason. Can someone walk me through it?

Upon further inspection, it seems I might want to find the children of all article classes?

Comment: I don’t have experience in the space, but, to help those that do that may see your question, could you provide more info regarding what you’ve tried. Some snippets of code, errors you’re seeing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To get correct page, it needs that correct `cookies=` are defined. Then we select all `<a> <h3 class="title">` to get links and titles.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.npr.org/?refresh=true'

cookies = {'choiceVersion': "1", 'dateOfChoice': "1584369909889", 'trackingChoice': "true"}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, cookies=cookies).content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('a[href]:has(h3.title)'):
    print('{:<90}{}'.format(a.h3.text, a['href']))
```

Prints:

```
Trump Told China To 'Go Ahead' With Prison Camps, Bolton Alleges In New Book              https://www.npr.org/2020/06/17/875876905/trump-told-china-to-go-ahead-with-concentration-camps-bolton-alleges-in-new-book
John Bolton Unloads On Former Boss Trump, Even If It's A Little Late Now                  https://www.npr.org/2020/06/17/879609378/john-bolton-unloads-on-former-boss-trump-even-if-its-a-little-late-now
Pompeo And China's Top Diplomat Meet In Hawaii As Relations Worsen                        https://www.npr.org/2020/06/18/879854568/pompeo-and-chinas-top-diplomat-meet-in-hawaii-as-relations-worsen
Former Atlanta Police Officer Who Shot Rayshard Brooks Charged With Felony Murder         https://www.npr.org/sections/live-updates-protests-for-racial-justice/2020/06/17/879509659/former-atlanta-police-officer-who-shot-rayshard-brooks-charged-with-felony-murde
Oakland Mayor Launches Hate Crime Investigation Into Nooses Found At Park                 https://www.npr.org/sections/live-updates-protests-for-racial-justice/2020/06/17/879758336/oakland-mayor-launches-hate-crime-investigation-into-nooses-found-at-park
Arbery Family Lawyer On Trump Meeting: 'He Doesn't Feel Like There's Systemic Racism'     https://www.npr.org/sections/live-updates-protests-for-racial-justice/2020/06/17/879682712/civil-rights-attorney-comments-on-his-meeting-with-president-trump
Tim Scott Says Dick Durbin's 'Token' Comment 'Hurts My Soul'                              https://www.npr.org/2020/06/17/879717148/tim-scott-says-dick-durbins-token-comment-hurts-my-soul
'From Here to Equality' Author Makes A Case, And A Plan, For Reparations                  https://www.npr.org/2020/06/17/879041052/william-darity-jr-discusses-reparations-racial-equality-in-his-new-book
'Hampton' No More: Man Sheds Family Name With Ties To Confederate General                 https://www.npr.org/sections/live-updates-protests-for-racial-justice/2020/06/17/879662628/hampton-no-more-man-sheds-family-name-with-ties-to-confederate-general
'Interrupt The Systems': Robin DiAngelo On 'White Fragility' And Anti-Racism              https://www.npr.org/2020/06/17/879136931/interrupt-the-systems-robin-diangelo-on-white-fragility-and-anti-racism
2020 Electoral Map Ratings: Biden Has An Edge Over Trump, With 5 Months To Go             https://www.npr.org/2020/06/17/877951588/2020-electoral-map-ratings-biden-has-an-edge-over-trump-with-5-months-to-go
Scientists Find The Biggest Soft-Shelled Egg Ever, Nicknamed 'The Thing'                  https://www.npr.org/2020/06/17/877679868/scientists-find-the-biggest-soft-shelled-egg-ever-nicknamed-the-thing
Justice Department Proposes Rolling Back Legal Protections For Online Platforms           https://www.npr.org/2020/06/17/879150136/doj-proposes-rolling-back-legal-protections-for-online-platforms
The Cameras Are Rolling On The Bold And The Beautiful                                     https://www.npr.org/sections/coronavirus-live-updates/2020/06/17/879773843/the-cameras-are-rolling-on-the-bold-and-the-beautiful
Why Now, White People?                                                                    https://www.npr.org/2020/06/16/878963732/why-now-white-people
Aunt Jemima Will Change Name, Image As Brands Confront Racial Stereotypes                 https://www.npr.org/sections/live-updates-protests-for-racial-justice/2020/06/17/879104818/acknowledging-racial-stereotype-aunt-jemima-will-change-brand-name-and-image
Northeast: Coronavirus-Related Restrictions By State                                      https://www.npr.org/2020/05/01/847331283/northeast-coronavirus-related-restrictions-by-state
South: Coronavirus-Related Restrictions By State                                          https://www.npr.org/2020/05/01/847415273/south-coronavirus-related-restrictions-by-state
West: Coronavirus-Related Restrictions By State                                           https://www.npr.org/2020/05/01/847416108/west-coronavirus-related-restrictions-by-state
Midwest: Coronavirus-Related Restrictions By State                                        https://www.npr.org/2020/06/11/847413697/midwest-coronavirus-related-restrictions-by-state
Amid Confusion About Reopening, An Expert Explains How To Assess COVID-19 Risk            https://www.npr.org/2020/06/17/879255417/amid-confusion-about-reopening-an-expert-explains-how-to-assess-covid-risk
TDC video carousel                                                                        https://www.npr.org/series/589466438/planet-money-shorts
5 Years After Charleston Church Massacre, What Have We Learned?                           https://www.npr.org/2020/06/17/878828088/5-years-after-charleston-church-massacre-what-have-we-learned
Ancient Bones Offer Clues To How Long Ago Humans Cared For The Vulnerable                 https://www.npr.org/sections/goatsandsoda/2020/06/17/878896381/ancient-bones-offer-clues-to-how-long-ago-humans-cared-for-the-vulnerable
Rita Indiana: La Monstra Returns With 'Black Sabbath Dembow'                              https://www.npr.org/2020/06/17/879316231/rita-indiana-la-monstra-returns-with-black-sabbath-dembow
Tracking The Pandemic: Are Coronavirus Cases Rising Or Falling In Your State?             https://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2020/03/16/816707182/map-tracking-the-spread-of-the-coronavirus-in-the-u-s
Which States Are Reopening? A State-By-State Guide                                        https://www.npr.org/2020/03/12/815200313/what-governors-are-doing-to-tackle-spreading-coronavirus
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `requests` module to download the page's HTML code, then parse it by `h3` tags, which I've noticed are used for headlines.

You can then use the `.find(string)` method to find such HTML tag, and when you do, find the next instance of `</h3>` from that index of the HTML code onward.

I couldn't understand which and how many headlines you want to parse, but you can use a `while` loop to keep parsing for every `h3` tag on the page, until you can't find a new one (the `.find()` method should return -1 if it doesn't locate the string).