# Getting headlines and headline links from a website with embedded links

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull current headlines with embdedded links similar to this stackoverflow post: [Getting the headlines and headline links from NPR.org with Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62438887/getting-the-headlines-and-headline-links-from-npr-org-with-beautiful-soup)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.npr.org/?refresh=true'

cookies = {'choiceVersion': "1", 'dateOfChoice': "1584369909889", 'trackingChoice': "true"}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, cookies=cookies).content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('a[href]:has(h3.title)'):
    print('{:<90}{}'.format(a.h3.text, a['href']))
```

However, I want it to pull headlines instead from https://www.npr.org/sections/environment/

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.npr.org/sections/environment/?refresh=true'

cookies = {'choiceVersion': "1", 'dateOfChoice': "1584369909889", 'trackingChoice': "true"}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, cookies=cookies).content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('a[href]:has(h2.title)'):
    print('{:<90}{}'.format(a.h2.text, a['href']))
```

It won't run when I change the url to that though. I updated the h3 tag to h2 to match the webpage. What else would need to be updated to make this run? I'm not sure if it's something with the cookies or not that needs to changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any problem with your code - besides the way you're extracting the headlines and links - so, I changed your as follows code and I got the results:

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Url and cookies: 
url = 'https://www.npr.org/sections/environment/?refresh=true'
cookies = {'choiceVersion': "1", 'dateOfChoice': "1584369909889", 'trackingChoice': "true"}

# List for append the results from the request.
results = []

# Make request: 
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, cookies=cookies).content, 'html.parser') #cookies=cookies

# Loop all "h2" HTML tags with "class='title'": 
for indx, h2 in enumerate(soup.findAll('h2', class_='title')): 
  # Add to the "results" list the headline and url of the headline: 
  results.append({
      "Headline" : h2.find("a").get_text("", strip=True), 
      "URL" : h2.find("a").get('href')
  })

# Build and print the dataframe: 
df_results = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df_results.to_markdown(tablefmt="grid"))
```

Results:

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    | Headline                                                                              | URL                                                                                                                        |
+====+=======================================================================================+============================================================================================================================+
|  0 | Ermias Kebreab: What do seaweed and cow burps have to do with climate change?         | https://www.npr.org/2022/05/20/1099945356/ermias-kebreab-what-do-seaweed-and-cow-burps-have-to-do-with-climate-change      |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Andrew Dent: How everyday materials can make innovative new products                  | https://www.npr.org/2022/05/20/1099939319/andrew-dent-how-everyday-materials-can-make-innovative-new-products              |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 | Gay Gordon-Byrne: Why do big manufacturers prevent you from repairing your own stuff? | https://www.npr.org/2022/05/20/1099934059/gay-gordon-byrne-why-do-big-manufacturers-prevent-you-from-repairing-your-own-st |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  3 | New Mexico wildfire sparks backlash against controlled burns. That's bad for the West | https://www.npr.org/2022/05/20/1099625787/new-mexico-wildfire-sparks-backlash-against-controlled-burns-thats-bad-for-the-w |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  4 | Foresters hope 'assisted migration' will preserve landscapes as the climate changes   | https://www.npr.org/2022/05/18/1098828128/foresters-assisted-migration-preserve-landscapes-climate-change                  |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  5 | Drought and soaring food prices from Ukraine war leave millions in Africa starving    | https://www.npr.org/2022/05/18/1099733752/famine-africa-ukraine-invasion-drought                                           |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  6 | The wildfires burning in the Southwest are bad but 'not unprecedented'                | https://www.npr.org/2022/05/16/1098779996/new-mexico-wildfires-southwest-not-unprecedented                                 |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  7 | Is your house at risk of a wildfire? This online tool could tell you                  | https://www.npr.org/2022/05/16/1098813861/wildfire-home-real-estate-risk-climate-change                                    |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  8 | A low-income energy-efficiency program gets $3.5B boost, but leaves out many in need  | https://www.npr.org/2022/05/13/1096114029/low-income-energy-efficient-weatherization-program-3-5b-needy                    |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  9 | Housing costs skyrocket as SpaceX expands in Texas city                               | https://www.npr.org/2022/05/13/1097981581/housing-costs-skyrocket-spacex-expands-texas                                     |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 10 | California just ran on 100% renewable energy, but fossil fuels aren't fading away yet | https://www.npr.org/2022/05/07/1097376890/for-a-brief-moment-calif-fully-powered-itself-with-renewable-energy              |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 11 | California's coastal fire has destroyed at least 20 homes                             | https://www.npr.org/2022/05/12/1098556183/california-coastal-fire-has-destroyed-at-least-20-homes                          |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 12 | A Climate Time Capsule, Part 2: The Start of the International Climate Change Fight   | https://www.npr.org/2022/05/05/1097000344/a-climate-time-capsule-part-2-the-start-of-the-international-climate-change-figh |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 13 | 'Succession' star James Cromwell glues his hand to a Starbucks counter in a protest   | https://www.npr.org/2022/05/11/1098162254/succession-actor-james-cromwell-glues-hand-starbucks-counter-protest             |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```